# Does HBase scan returns sorted columns?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am working on a HBase map reduce job and need to understand if the columns in a single column family are returned sorted by their names (key). If so, I wouldnt need to do it in the shuffle sort stage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar data model as you. Upon insertion however, I set my own values for the timestamps on the Put object. However, I did so in a way that took a "seed" of the current time and appended a incrementing counter for each event I persisted in the batch.

When I pulled the results out from the Scan, I wrote a comparator:

```
public class KVTimestampComparator implements Comparator<KeyValue> {

    @Override
    public int compare(KeyValue kv1, KeyValue kv2) {
        Long kv1Timestamp = kv1.getTimestamp();
        Long kv2Timestamp = kv2.getTimestamp();

        return kv1Timestamp.compareTo(kv2Timestamp);
    }
}
```

Then sorted the raw row:

```
List<KeyValue> row = Arrays.asList(result.raw());
Collections.sort(row, new KVTimestampComparator());
```

Got this idea from person who answered this : [Sorted results from hbase scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244597/sorted-results-from-hbase-scanner)

Answer (score -2):

no, columns are not sorted
They are stored internally as key-value pairs in a long byte array.  But, you should clarify your question about what you actually need this for.

Comment: My system tracks some kind of events. Each row key is the source id and day, and each column is the event id and data. This structure seems right since I always need an entire day's events rather than a single one. When analyzing the events I need them sorted by id. I will usually do this on the map and sort/shuffle stage and leave the computation for the reduce, but if they are already sorted i can skip it and do the entire computation on the map stage.

Comment: If all of the data you need is in the one row, then why not just sort it in memory using conventional data structures / operations?  The shuffle/sort/reduce phase is very expensive.

Comment: Columns are indeed sorted. See: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/24414