# Row retrieval during scan in hbase

Tags: hbase

I have a doubt regarding the order in which the rows are retrieved in Hbase during the table scan. If my row-keys are as follows ;

id1,id2,id3,id4,id5

I know that they are stored in sorted(ascending) order can you tell me if they are retrieved in the same order as well ie ;

id1,id2,id3,id4,id5

Comment: Check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244597/sorted-results-from-hbase-scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are restored in the same order. When you scan, there are 2 ways to retrieve the results.

A) Retrieve each row one by one, where a marker is maintained, and incremented on every get.
scannerGet()

B) Retrieve n number of rows at once, where the order is maintained.
scannerGetList(numberofrowsreqd). You can do this in a while loop.

```
while(true)
{
  List<TRowResult> list = scannerGetList(scannerId,numberofRows);
  if(list.Count == 0)
  {
   break;
  }
}
```